# Can't get a button to execute Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

I wrote some html/css/javascript code that was taken verbatim from a javascript textbook.  For some reason, the code does not run correctly in my browser (which is the newest version of Firefox).  When I click the button, the javascript function "toggleStyle()" does not execute in the browser at ALL.  This is the code for the button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleStyle()">Toggle Style</button>
```

This is the javascript coding.  Note that when I click the button, not even the alert() method is executed:

```
        function toggleStyle() {
        alert("toggleStyle() is working.");
        var divMessage = document.getElementById("divMessage");

        if (divMessage.className === "message-style1") {
            divMessage.className = "";
        }
        else {
            divMessage.className = "message-style1";
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried checking Firefox's error console? Press `Ctrl+Shift+J` (if on Windows) to bring up any possible errors or warnings that may be causing the code to execute improperly. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Error_Console if it isn't enabled for you by default.

Comment: Is there another `}` to end the function?

Comment: You forgot the closing '}' for your function.

Comment: Where have you defined the function (location)  ? Can you post the full HTML code including JavaScript ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you put the code inside `<script type="text/javascript">`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleStyle() {
        alert("toggleStyle() is working.");
        var divMessage = document.getElementById("divMessage");

        if (divMessage.className === "message-style1") {
            divMessage.className = "";
        }
        else {
            divMessage.className = "message-style1";
        }
}
</script>
```

The above code is working:

[image]

Comment: @Michael Seeley: so as others have said: the problem may be the end closing tag } you're forgetting. Copy/past my answer's code and try once more...

Comment: Haha, wow, that worked.  My gosh, I feel like such a noobie right now.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

For starters, I don't see the end `}` brace; do you have one?

Also, where is the function defined? Does the script get loaded? Are there any errors?